# Mongoose: Returning await for asynchronous operations

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await, webstorm

When using Mongoose I am confused about the ESLint messages for `return [await] async_function_call(<args>)`

Using Mongoose, consider the simple functions `createUser` and `findUserByEmail` below:

```
interface IUser {
    _id: Types.ObjectId;
    userName: string;
    email: string;
}

const createUser = async (
    user: Partial<IUser>
): Promise<IUser | null> => {
    const newUser = new User(user);
    // *Webstorm inspection error*: Always use 'await' for async function calls to avoid mistakes and to help V8 async stack traces 
    return newUser.save();
};
```

For the `save` method, ESLint wants an `await`. On the other hand, for `findOne`, it objects:

```
const findUserByEmail = async (
    email: string
): Promise<IUser | null> => {
    const filter: FilterQuery<IUser> = {
        email: email
    };
    // ESLint error: Redundant 'return await' 
    // Note that Webstorm does not give inspection error if `await` omitted
    return *await* User.findOne(filter);
};
```

In which case(s) should I use `await` as part of the return statement and why do they differ?

Edit: clarified that the missing `await` error is a Webstorm inspection (which occurs only in the first case) and not an ESLint error

Comment: There is no point to `return await xxx()` (unless it's in a `try/catch`).  The `await` is pointless and `return xxx()` would be better.  If ESLint is telling you to insert the `await` there, then it's just wrong.

Comment: Remove `async` if you don't use `await` keyword in your function.

Comment: Maybe it's worth asking here https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues

Comment: So it's actually a webstorm inspection issue (clarified). Filed a bug at webstorm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-60957/Inconsistent-inspection-errors-with-return-await-mongoose?c=relates%20to%20WEB-31269

Also a related webstorm issue (linked in above issue) had a comment pointing here (which *does* recommend `return await` for stack tracing
https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices/blob/master/sections/errorhandling/returningpromises.md